# Why does "Get Board Info" not work, but I can still program my Arduino Nano?

Tags: arduino-nano

Dear Stack Exchangers,

I have been working with Arduinos for probably 10 years, and as a habit the first thing I do when I connect a device to the USB port is run the "Tools > Get Board Info" in the Arduino IDE just to make sure I've got the correct port selected, USB cable is good, etc.

Well tonight when I connected a Nano, the "Get Board Info" didn't work at all. So after spending hours rebooting, trying different cables, etc. I eventually just tried uploading a sketch, and that worked fine! But the "Get Board Info" still does not work.

Anybody have any ideas what is going on? Thanks!

Sincerely,
Ramblin' Wreck

Comment: By "Nano" you're referring to the ATMega328P based original Nano? Or one of a pile of other board's with that in the name? When it "doesn't work" what _does_ it do instead? Which IDE version?

Comment: It has "NANO" printed on the board. Today though, the "Get Board Info" command works fine and I receive the following message:
BN: Unknown board
VID: 1A86
PID: 7523
SN: Upload any sketch to obtain it
- I am using Arduino 1.8.13 on a Dell laptop with Windows 10.

Comment: To be clear, you were _not_ getting that message before? If so, what _were_ you getting? The content of the message in you are currently getting is in line with Juraj's answer.

Comment: Timemage, correct, I was NOT getting that message before. No message window popped up at all. I notice that today the Nano is on COM7 (used Device Manager to determine this), and last night it was on COM5. So perhaps that has something to do with it.

Comment: Odd. You should have received one of [these messages](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/1.8.19/app/src/processing/app/Editor.java#L2434-L2444) instead of nothing at all.

Answer (score 2):

The classic Arduino Nano uses an FTDI chip as USB to TTL Serial adapter. Many Nano (and Uno and Mega) clones use the CH340 as USB adapter. These USB chips present themselves with id set by the USB chip manufacturer. This doesn't provide a way to identify the specific board.

Original Uno and Mega Rev 3 and some clones use ATmega16u2 as USB adapter with a firmware by Arduino. Arduino sets the USB id in the firmware so it can identify as specific board type. (People reported Mega clones which presented itself as Uno).

The boards with MCU with native USB like Leonardo, Micro and ARM boards (Zero, MKR, Nano IoT, Nano BLE) provide the USB id set in boards.txt so they can be identified too.